# How To change color and font of several subtitles together?

Tags: subtitle

I have a number of srt files with subtitles. I want to change all of them together + change the font, is there a command for this?

Comment: Unless you still need help and update your question to include details specific to the player running in Ubuntu, this question should probably be closed for being off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

`.srt` files handle the subtitle content and position only. Font, colour etc. is managed by your video player. Have a look at its settings.

Comment: I want to edit with Subtitle Edit itself

Answer (score 1):

`.srt` format: contents and syntax.

1. Item number
2. Display item schedule
3. Text body

And the allowed HTML tags on text are:

- **Bold** <b>...</b>
- *Italic* <i>...</i>
- Underline <u>...</u>
- Font color <font color="name or #code">...</font>

Font color works depends on the player, I see VLC and mpv (smplayer) implements these but not with Totem Ubuntu Gnome Videos.

Sample of the .srt code

```
1
00:00:05,000 --> 00:00:06,000
Welcome to AskUbuntu

2
00:00:07,000 --> 00:00:08,000
<i>This is a forum;
<font color="blue">which noob teaches another noob.</font></i>

3
00:00:09,000 --> 00:00:10,000
<b>Enjoy yourself</b>
<i>and don't get lost.</i>
```

[image: smplayer]

Comment: I want to easily change the color and font of 100 subtitles so that I can attach them to the desired videos for hard subtitle playback in the video.

Comment: Yes, you can. Install `smplayer` and go to preferences.

Comment: @Ahmadmoosavi for bulk editing you can probably write up some script. Off-topic here.